# Django: {{form.comment}} area size

Tags: django, forms, comments, size, textfield

I use standart django comments framework.

template:

```
<h2>Add comment</h2> {%  get_comment_form for post as form %} 
<form  action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post" > {% csrf_token %}   
{{form.content_type}}{{form.object_pk}}{{form.timestamp}}{{form.security_hash}}
Comment:<br />
{{form.comment}}

<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}#comment" /> 

<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>

</form>
```

How can I change `{{form.comment}}` field size? I tried to wrap it in `<p>` or `<div>` but it didn't work. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added something like this

```
#id_comment {
width: 95% !important; 
height: 200px !important; 
resize: none !important; 
}
```

to my CSS-file. It's working!

Answer (score 3):

There are several options:

1) You can use [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks). In that case you write `{{form.comment|attr:"cols:10"|attr:"rows:10"}}` and that will result in:

```
<textarea id="id_comment" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>
```

2) You can also notice that the id of the textarea will be `id_comment`. Thus you can control say the width with your css:

```
textarea#id_comment {width:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just inspected `contrib.comments` app and I don't see any way you could customize widget without creating your own comment app. The easiest solution would be just to create a regular HTML text input or textarea with `name="comment" and id="id_comment"`

Comment: I tried that but on posting my comment, it would throw error that I cannot leave comment filed blank.